# adding records to a dropdown box json ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

```
success: function( jsondata, textStatus, jQxhr ){
    $.each(jsondata.data, function(key,value){
        $("#student").append("<option value=" + value.id + ">" + value.name + "</option>");
    });
```

I am attempting to take data from a database and add it to a dropdown box. The problem is any guide I follow I get this error:

> jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

**UPDATE**
not gotten very far

PHP:

`$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT CustomerID, FirstName FROM customer"); $sql->execute(); $row = $sql->fetchAll(); //var_dump ($row); //$para = implode(" ",$row); echo json_encode($row); //echo json_encode(array('data'=>$result));`

Javascript:

`$.each(jsondata.data, function(key,value){ $("#student").append( "<option value=" + value.CustomerID +">"+value.FirstName+"</option>" ); });`

Console:

```
[{"CustomerID":"2","0":"2","FirstName":"John","1":"John"},{"CustomerID":"3","0":"3","FirstName":"William","1":"William"}]
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Based on this tutorial:http://www.plus2net.com/jquery/dropdown-list.php

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this is what I got back `{"data":{"CustomerID":"2","FirstName":"John"}}`

Comment: That's not an array you can loop through; it's an object that can only contain one set of values. You can get rid of the `$.each` and just append `jsondata.data.CustomerID` and `jsondata.data.FirstName`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan... You're right, but in all fairness, Javascript objects are arrays and he could still loop through that response, they keys would be "CustomerID" and "FirstName", even though it's not necessary. If he ever received multiple customers data back then the loop would be relevant. Though using value.id, value.name is incorrect.

Comment: @JeramiahHarland  updated hopefully makes more sence what i am trying to do, thank you for your help

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan updated hopefully makes more sence what i am trying to do, thank you for your help